# Find rectangle around point with python?

Tags: python, coordinates, clip, pyproj, geographiclib

Given a point, latitude and longitude, how would one find the coordinates of a rectangle centered on that point with a known width and height in meters? I tried using the Geodesic stuff from geographiclib in python to compute the rectangle coordinates, but the resulting rectangle has the wrong aspect ratio. The general idea here is to compute a rectangle around a given point and then use that rectangle to clip LANDSAT 8 imagery to a final image with a known aspect ratio.

Sorry if this is a dumb question, I've just started doing work with GIS recently.

[EDIT]

I tried modifying my code to do something like what the first answer below does, but this doesn't quite work for me, I run into the same problem I was having before, when I clip the landsat tiff I get an image with the wrong aspect ratio. The command I'm using to clip the geotiff looks something like this
    `gdalwarp -of gtiff -t_srs EPSG:4326 -te <bounds from the polygon that I calculated> input.tif output.tif.` 
The width and height I used should give me an image with an aspect ratio of 1.6 but instead I get an image with an aspect ratio of about 1.9 or so.

Comment: What about to convert lat, lon to plan coordinates (e.g. using web mercator projection or to the projection that will be used to display images) and define there the rectangle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's some example code using pyproj. Given a point in lat lon, it calculates new lat lon points given a distance in meters and an azimuth. The azimuth comes from the aspect ratio of the rectangle.

```
from math import sqrt,atan,pi
import pyproj
geod = pyproj.Geod(ellps='WGS84')

width = 10000. # m
height = 20000. # m
rect_diag = sqrt( width**2 + height**2 )

center_lon = -78.6389
center_lat = 35.7806

azimuth1 = atan(width/height)
azimuth2 = atan(-width/height)
azimuth3 = atan(width/height)+pi # first point + 180 degrees
azimuth4 = atan(-width/height)+pi # second point + 180 degrees

pt1_lon, pt1_lat, _ = geod.fwd(center_lon, center_lat, azimuth1*180/pi, rect_diag)
pt2_lon, pt2_lat, _ = geod.fwd(center_lon, center_lat, azimuth2*180/pi, rect_diag)
pt3_lon, pt3_lat, _ = geod.fwd(center_lon, center_lat, azimuth3*180/pi, rect_diag)
pt4_lon, pt4_lat, _ = geod.fwd(center_lon, center_lat, azimuth4*180/pi, rect_diag)

wkt_point = 'POINT (%.6f %.6f)' % (center_lon, center_lat)
wkt_poly = 'POLYGON (( %.6f %.6f, %.6f %.6f, %.6f %.6f, %.6f %.6f, %.6f %.6f ))' % (pt1_lon, pt1_lat, pt2_lon, pt2_lat, pt3_lon, pt3_lat, pt4_lon, pt4_lat, pt1_lon, pt1_lat)
```

The documentation for pyproj.Geod can be found [here](https://pyproj.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/pyproj.Geod-class.html).

Below is a screenshot of the point (yellow) and rectangle (green) in QGIS:
[image]

Comment: This doesn't quite work for me, I run into the same problem I was having before, when clip the landsat tiff I get an image with the wrong aspect ratio. The command I'm using to clip the geotiff looks something like this: gdalwarp -of gtiff -t_srs EPSG:4326 -te <bounds from the polygon i obtained> input.tif output.tif. The width and height I used should give me an image with an aspect ratio of 1.6 but instead i get an image with an aspect ratio of about 1.9.

Comment: Ok, hopefully we can chase this down. So the code I provided gives the *same* undesired result? Does the clipping polygon itself have the correct aspect ratio? Does the landsat tile completely contain the polygon? I can see how the result could have the wrong aspect ratio if they do not completely overlap. You could drop the tiff into QGIS and use the QuickWKT plugin to make the polygon. Maybe visualizing them at the same time might give insight into the problem.

Comment: Ooops, messed up on that last comment, here's my actual reply:
>> So the code I provided gives the same undesired result? 
Yes
>> Does the clipping polygon itself have the correct aspect ratio? 
No, it has the same incorrect aspect ratio I think.
>> Does the landsat tile completely contain the polygon?
Yes, I checked that already.

Comment: Glad we ruled out the polygon generation step. How are you measuring aspect ratio? I wonder if the aspect ratio of the result is measured in pixels, i.e., width/height of the pixels in the clipped image. And if the pixel resolution is tied to degrees, then it won't seem to have the same aspect ratio as it would in linear units. I.e., squares aren't squares when draped over spheres kind of thing. Can you try to convert it to UTM and see what the aspect ratio is with a linear unit, or post the image so I can?

Comment: Maybe plug your clipping coordinates into here: http://www.rcn.montana.edu/resources/converter.aspx to get the utm zone. Convert your landsat to UTM using gdal_translate, and try to clip the image in a linear CRS to see if the image actually has a different aspect ratio than you expect.

Comment: So, the way I’m doing this is as follows. I want a rectangle that is 30 or so miles wide and has an aspect ratio of 1.6. I convert all those measurements to meters and then compute the actual points of the rectangle using the geodesic library. At this point, if I measure the aspect ratio of the rectangle (where aspect = (right longitude - left longitude)/(top latitude - bottom latitude)) the aspect ratio is already wrong, as I get 1.9 instead of 1.6. This is the same bad aspect ratio that I end up with in the final image in pixels. The landsat image i’m trying to clip is: https://goo.gl/xykaqK

Comment: This to be expected, right? If the a 30 mi square (aspect ratio of 1) were on the north pole, the longitude would range 180 degrees, but the latitude would only range less than a degree. The aspect ratio (in degrees) would be very off of 1. Another way to think of it is that a 1 degree lat by 1 degree lon tile has a different area at the equator than it does at the north pole. I suspect your clipped result actually does have the correct aspect ratio in linear units, but you can't expect for it to have the same aspect ratio in degrees.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds right, but then how do I generate a rectangle that will result in an image with the right aspect ratio when I clip the tile?

Comment: Aha! I think i got it. You were right to say that I should use UTM coordinates instead! I manually converted the latitude and longitude to UTM and then changed the gdalwarp command to `gdalwarp -of gtiff -t_srs EPSG:26911 -te <UTM coordinates> input.tif output.tif` and I ended up with an image of the correct aspect ratio. Thanks again!

Comment: Excellent, glad we figured it out.